# Castor Error : forward references are not supprted

Tags: java, xml, castor

Castor was attempting to marshall my object to XML and threw the error stating that "forward references are not supported"
I had 3 java classes

```
public class RandomTransactionRequest extends TransactionRequest {
   public RandomTransactionRequest() { super("location") }
}

public class TransactionRequest extends ServiceRequest {
   private StatusObject status;
   public TransactionRequest (String destination) {
      setDestination(destination);
   }
}

public class ServiceRequest {
     private String destination;
     public String getDestination(){ return destination; }
     public void setDestination(String destination) { this.destination = destination; }
 }
```

I was expecting XML that looked like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<REQUEST>
  <DEST>location</DEST>
  <STATUS_FIELDS>
    <STATUS>
      <INIT_STAT>incomplete</INIT_STAT>
      <FIN_STAT>complete</FIN_STAT>
    </STATUS>
  </STATUS_FIELDS>
</REQUEST>
```

My Castor mapping for Class A looked like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mapping>
    <class name="com.package.requests.RandomTransactionRequest" extends="com.package.requests.TransactionRequest">
    <map-to xml="REQUEST"/>
</class>
<class name="com.package.requests.TransactionRequest" extends="com.package.requests.ServiceRequest">
    <field name="status" type="com.package.objects.StatusObject">
        <bind-xml name="STATUS" location="APP"/>
    </field>
</class>
<class name="com.package.requests.ServiceRequest" >
    <field name="destination" type="java.lang.String">
        <bind-xml name="DEST" />
    </field>
</class>
<class name="com.package.objects.StatusObject" >
    <field name="initialStatus" type="java.lang.String">
        <bind-xml name="INIT_STAT"/>
    </field>
    <field name="finalStatus" type="java.lang.String">
        <bind-xml name="FIN_STAT"/>
    </field>
</class>
</mapping>
```

Received error:

> No class descriptor found for extended class org.exolab.castor.mapping.xml.ClassMapping@48584858         in class com.package.requests.RandomTransactionRequest -- forward references are not supported

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing was adding a default constructor to TransactionRequest. Castor needs to be able to instantiate the classes you're mapping and needs a default constructor to do so.

My final class looked like this:

```
 public class TransactionRequest extends ServiceRequest {
   private StatusObject status;

   public TransactionRequest () {}   /* NEEDED DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR */

   public TransactionRequest (String destination) {
      setDestination(destination);
   }
 }
```